# How to pass TFS's changes from one job to other through pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have one step in Jenkins called *xxx-Checkout* to trigger the TFS checkout and get the code, then that job triggers a pipeline which builds another job called *xxx-Build*. The question is how can I pass the checkout's changes to the pipeline job because with one job to other without pipelines works but in the pipeline doesn't. I can't see the changes made in the checkout job.

This is how I trigger the build:

[image]

And here shows me that there are no changes even though there are:

[image]

Comment: Not clear the detail workflow for me, can you provide the sample to explain it? On the other hand, do you check the env variables for future build steps? https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin

Comment: Please add the pipeline's code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom workspace for both jobs or pass the "custom workspace" as a parameter to the pipeline job.

**Upstream job - Freestyle project**

1) Configure a custom workspace: Go to your job > advanced > tick "Use custom workspace":

[image: Freestyle - custom workspace]

2) Trigger the pipeline job using the [Parametrized Trigger 
 Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

**Downstream job - Pipeline**

Use the same custom workspace:

```
node{
    stage('build'){
       dir('D:\\Jenkins\\shared')  {
        //some code
       }      
    }
}
```

Comment: All jobs shared a customo worskpace, the problem is tha job A trigger the Pipeline X, X trigger jobs B and C.

I cant see the changes in jobs A,X and B but not in C.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Do you mean you are able to share the workspace beetwen A, X and B, but not with C?